# Write and Read protobuf message into dynamodb having a oneof field in Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, protocol-buffers

I am having a message as:

```
message CanRead {
  optional string s = 1;
}

message CanWrite {
  optional string s = 1;
}

message MyMessage {
  optional string name = 1;
  oneof capability {
    optional CanRead r = 2;
    optional CanWrite w = 3;
  }
```

Now, I have two questions before implementation and deciding to use Protobuffers:

1. Can I save `MyMessage` binary serialization into dynamodb and deserialize them back and figure out capability field value and its type?
2. How about if I want to just save `capability` field as an attribute in my record? Can I read the field and deserialize it back to the correct type?

PS: The choice of DynamoDB cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not directly support protobuf payloads, but it can support binary data. So you can convert your protobuf to base64 and store it in DynamoDB as a binary attribute value.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But even then, can I retrieve it back and deserialize? What if I only serialize capability? Can this be deserialized? If so, how can I do that and which class should I use?